# Цикл, расчет обратной матрицы

Tags: sql, база-данных, sybase

Есть некий цикл, который считает обратную матрицу:

```
set @n= (select count(distinct l.cod_row) from  ltb_Matrix l);

set @i=1;
while   @i <= @n loop --5
        set  @j = 1;
        while  @j <= @n * 2 loop 
        if @j <> @i then 
            set @val_temp_j = (select l.value from ltb_Matrix l  where l.cod_row = @j and l.cod_col = @i);
            set @val_temp_i = (select l.value from ltb_Matrix l  where l.cod_row = @i and l.cod_col = @i);

                if @val_temp_i=0  or @val_temp_j=0
                then set @d = 0;
                else  set  @d =@val_temp_j/@val_temp_i 
                ;end if;

                update ltb_Matrix l
                set l.value = l.value - (m.value*@d)
                from ltb_Matrix l
                inner join ltb_Matrix m on l.cod_col=m.cod_col
                where m.cod_row = @i
                and l.cod_row = @j
                ;commit;
        end if;

set @j =@j+1;
end loop;
set @i =@i+1;
end loop;


update ltb_Matrix l
set l.value =l.value/m.value
from ltb_Matrix l
inner join (select l.cod_row, l.value from ltb_Matrix l where l.cod_row = l.cod_col
)m on l.cod_row= m.cod_row
;commit;
```

Проблема в том, что расчет идет довольно. Матрица 300х300 считается более 3-х часов. Проблема как мне кажется именно в while. Заменить на WITH не могу т.к. Sybase не поддерживает. Может кто стыкался с оптимизацией while.Буду благодарен

---

Спасибо.
Решил проблему заменой цикла на курсор!

Answer (score 1):

зачем решать задачи линейной алгебры в СУБД???

Возьмите любой язык программирования и реализуйте это в нем.

Пример на Python:

```
In [280]: import numpy as np

In [281]: from scipy.linalg import inv, solve

In [282]: m = np.random.rand(300, 300)

In [283]: m.shape
Out[283]: (300, 300)

In [284]: %timeit m_inv = inv(m)
2.53 ms ± 185 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Расчет обратной матрицы размерности 300 x 300 занял 2.53 милисекунды...

PS на C/C++ скорее всего еще быстрее получится...

Comment: К сожалению, в условиях Банка один инструмент-sybase(

Comment: Может быть кто вкурсе как заменить цикл на запрос?)